# IndexOf returning -1 but list has the element

Tags: java, arrays, list

The question has not been answered in the one proposed. It doesn't even have an answer marked.

I'm really not getting what's happening. I have a list of Objects filled with elements, but if I do indexOf(element) it keeps returning -1 .
These are the checks I do:

```
Crime oldCrime = this.service.getCrimeById(319L);
        System.out.println("ID old crime " + oldCrime.getId());
        System.out.println("Index " + this.service.getAllCrimes().indexOf(oldCrime));
        int oldSize = this.service.getAllCrimes().size();
        for (Crime c : this.service.getAllCrimes()) {
            System.out.println("Crime id " + c.getId());
        }
```

And this is the output:

[image]

So oldCrime exists in the list, all the crimes from the list are present because I can print their id, but the method indexOf called on the same list returns -1.
Probably it's a stupid error but I can't really figure it out.

```
public class Crime {


    @CsvBindByName(column = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "zipCode")
    @NonNull
    private int zipCode;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "totPopulation")
    @NonNull
    private int totPopulation;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "medianAge")
    @NonNull
    private double medianAge;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "totMales")
    @NonNull
    private int totMales;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "totFemales")
    @NonNull
    private int totFemales;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "totHouseholds")
    @NonNull
    private int totHouseholds;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "avgHouseholdSize")
    @NonNull
    private double avgHouseholdSize;



    /**
     * @param id
     * @param zipCode
     * @param totPopulation
     * @param medianAge
     * @param totMales
     * @param totFemales
     * @param totHouseholds
     * @param avgHouseholdSize
     */
    public Crime(long id, int zipCode, int totPopulation, double medianAge, int totMales, int totFemales,
            int totHouseholds, double avgHouseholdSize) { 
        this.id = id;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.totPopulation = totPopulation;
        this.medianAge = medianAge;
        this.totMales = totMales;
        this.totFemales = totFemales;
        this.totHouseholds = totHouseholds;
        this.avgHouseholdSize = avgHouseholdSize;
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    public Crime() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.zipCode = 0;
        this.totPopulation = 0;
        this.medianAge = 0;
        this.totMales = 0;
        this.totFemales = 0;
        this.totHouseholds = 0;
        this.avgHouseholdSize = 0;
    }

    /**
     * @param id
     */
    public Crime(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.zipCode = (int)id;
        this.totPopulation = (int)id;
        this.medianAge = (int)id;
        this.totMales = (int)id;
        this.totFemales = (int)id;
        this.totHouseholds = (int)id;
        this.avgHouseholdSize = (int)id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }




    public int getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }



    public void setZipCode(int zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }



    public int getTotPopulation() {
        return totPopulation;
    }



    public void setTotPopulation(int totPopulation) {
        this.totPopulation = totPopulation;
    }



    public double getMedianAge() {
        return medianAge;
    }



    public void setMedianAge(double medianAge) {
        this.medianAge = medianAge;
    }



    public int getTotMales() {
        return totMales;
    }



    public void setTotMales(int totMales) {
        this.totMales = totMales;
    }



    public int getTotFemales() {
        return totFemales;
    }



    public void setTotFemales(int totFemales) {
        this.totFemales = totFemales;
    }



    public int getTotHouseholds() {
        return totHouseholds;
    }



    public void setTotHouseholds(int totHouseholds) {
        this.totHouseholds = totHouseholds;
    }



    public double getAvgHouseholdSize() {
        return avgHouseholdSize;
    }



    public void setAvgHouseholdSize(double avgHouseholdSize) {
        this.avgHouseholdSize = avgHouseholdSize;
    }


}
```

Comment: the size doesn't guarantee anything of the contents. as you can see, 1, 2 and 5 aren't there either. Also: how is the equals of your Crime class?

Comment: Could you show `Crime` class?

Comment: @Stultuske I'm not basing this on the size, I know 319 is there since is printed and since I have it in my file.

Comment: Are you sure `getCrimeById(id)` will only return items that are present in `getAllCrimes()` ?

Comment: Did you have equals() and hashCode() implemented in Crime class?

Comment: @Aaron yes I'm sure. I've edited the question with the Crime class

Comment: Without the equals function override, it is not possible to find the correct object. He will compare with some defautl hashCode. You should override the equals function by defining your own. Here it should be something where id of one equal of id of the other.

Comment: the indexOf will call equals. So either you write the worst equals in the world (myCrime.equals(possibleId) should not work) or you need to use another approach

Comment: @kevingiroux since the equals won't be called on the id, but on the Crime itself, the approach itself should be corrected

Comment: @Stultuske yes i know, but here the part that he want to be equal is the id of the crime. Normally you should compare with all the part of your class it is relevant to compare to defined identify or similarity between object.

Comment: though it will work, chances are he'll need a decent equals in the future. then this will just ruin his project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`indexOf` does a comparison based on `equals` method. Override `equals` in your Crime class otherwise it will be a reference comparison.

Comment: it will fail either way. it's basically myCrime.equals(someId);

Comment: No it does not fail. This way is correct.